# Why macro redefined error occurs only when value is different and Macro name is same?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I found below macro defined in two header files of one of third party library

```
# define RATES_BALANCE_SCALER                  1000000
```

To date no error comes but as I change the value of that macro in one file then following error started

```
error: "RATES_BALANCE_SCALER" redefined [-Werror]
```

Note: In compilation have set warning as error.

so can you please confirm my below understanding for compiler right or wrong?

1. MACRO replacement done at preprocessing time so when pre processor
   find same name macro with different value then it will replace macro
   value with later added header file and also generate error/warning
   right?
2. Now when MACRO name and value both are same then compiler will not
       generate any error/warning and replacement done by macro of later
       added header file right? If right then why in this situation
       compiler not generating warning or error?

Comment: Because that's what the language standard says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have the same name, so it is the same macro you're changing. But it is present in two files. As long as the value is the same there is no problem, but when you change the value the compiler can't figure out which one is the "right" one. This causes a conflict. Try not to define a value in more than one file. But if necessary put

```
#ifndef RATES_BALANCE_SCALER
#define RATES_BALANCE_SCALER 1000000
#endif
```

so that, if the value is already defined, it will not be redefined.

edit: This will cause the value to not change, if the third party macro is defined first! If you need the value, name it something different

Answer (score 2):

Just defining the same thing as two different ones should be a programming error.  This is the reason that the compiler emits an error when you redefine it differently.  The compiler has support to `#undef` it and redefine differently, but there's no consensus on what you may mean on redefining a macro substitution.

Good compilers should emit an error when redefining a macro as a different thing and a warning when doing it several times (to the same string) but, as there's much legacy code that simply redefines the same constant in several places to ensure you finnaly get the definition, normally the compiler gets silent on it.